# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' despite no references

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, reportviewer

I've encountered this error message in my ASP.NET projects, but this latest instance really baffles me because nowhere in my project can I find any references to ReportViewer. Looking for any suggestions on how to figure out where this is coming from. Below is the stack trace info:

```
    [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +457
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +729
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +69
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +226
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +73
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +321
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +170
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +878

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was never able to determine why I was getting the error described above, I discovered a workaround by copying a bunch of assemblies into the project's \bin folder from one of my other working applications on this server. These assemblies included:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.*
Microsoft.AI.Web
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.AspNet.*
```

... and several others. It's still troubling me why this was even necessary since the code worked fine on not only my dev machine, but another test web server to which I first deployed it. If my project has no verifiable references to these things, yet still depends on them, then I would expect the publish tool should ensure that these dependencies are being deployed along with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the Asp.Net controls require support from report viewer library to render the output. So, Try to install the package [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916) and then try to compile the solution. You might have removed this in your installation process or later inadvertently.

You could also try to go and check if you have the [Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms] and related assemblies listed in the GAC [C:\Windows\assembly] folder. If not it is not found there , then it is a clear indication that the implicit dependencies are not available in your workstation.

Comment: The thing is that I am explicitly using the ReportViewer in another ASP.NET project on my dev machine of which I had earlier deployed to the same target web server and everything works fine. So this latest app is the second one I am deploying to the server. It obviously has all of the ReportViewer dependencies already in place. Since my new project doesn't have any reporting functionality, I'd like to eradicate this false dependency if possible.